# DJango won't find virtual env

Tags: python, django, apache

I am a n00b trying to get django working with apache on a new installation.
the test server on port 8000 works fine but apache does not.
It appears as though apache cannot read the virtual environment

error in logs:

```
[Mon Apr 03 17:14:32.560566 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10799] [client 72.178.8.113:37774] mod_wsgi (pid=10799): Target WSGI script '/home/palace/palace/palace/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Apr 03 17:14:32.560944 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10799] [client 72.178.8.113:37774] mod_wsgi (pid=10799): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/palace/palace/palace/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Apr 03 17:14:32.561249 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10799] [client 72.178.8.113:37774] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Apr 03 17:14:32.561338 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10799] [client 72.178.8.113:37774]   File "/home/palace/palace/palace/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Mon Apr 03 17:14:32.561386 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10799] [client 72.178.8.113:37774]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Apr 03 17:14:32.561470 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10799] [client 72.178.8.113:37774] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.persiaspalace.us

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/palace/
        WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/palace/palace/:/home/palace/vpalace/bin:/home/palace/vpalace/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
        #WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/palace/vpalace/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ python-path=/home/palace/palace/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/palace/palace/palace/wsgi.py
        #WSGIPythonHome /home/palace/vpalace/
        #WSGIPythonPath /home/palace/palace/
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        Alias /static /home/palace/
        <Directory /home/palace/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
         </Directory>

        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

django is installed in virtual environment:

```
(vpalace) root@pieceofshiot:/home/palace# pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in ./vpalace/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Directory permissions structure:
files are 0644 and directories are 0744

```
(vpalace) root@pieceofshiot:/home/palace# ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    0 Apr  3 04:14 index.php.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  807 Apr  2 22:36 manage.py
drwxr--r-- 3 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  2 22:46 palace
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  2 22:32 vpalace
```

django version:

```
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 10, 6, 'final', 0)
```

mod_wsgi version:

```
ii  libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3                    4.3.0-1.1build1                                  amd64        Python 3 WSGI adapter module for Apache
```

How do I get django running on apache/ubuntu?

Comment: did you install `mod_wsgi`? Did you load it in apache config file?

Comment: @RaviKumar  libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 is installed.  my complete config is in the post.  I followed https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/  with the exception of python-home which I got from #django on freenode.

Comment: Please look at this https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi#connecting-into-apache-installation

Comment: @RaviKumar that looks like 2.7 code?
I am using Python 3.5.  I don't even have a mod_wsgi-express command

Comment: It worked for me on Python 3.5 .You need to `pip install mod_wsgi` in virtualenv for `mod_wsgi-express module-config` to work.

Comment: Your `WSGIPythonHome` should also point to your virtualenv.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @nomad Ubuntu  https://bpaste.net/show/932b634b6b52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/palace/palace/:/home/palace/vpalace/bin:/home/palace/vpalace/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
    #WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/palace/vpalace/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ python-path=/home/palace/palace/
```

were wrong attempts. The commented out one was closest but still wrong.

Go read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

on how to set up Python virtual environments.

The `python-home` option should specify a single directory (not a list) which is the root of the Python virtual environment (not `site-packages`). It should be what `sys.prefix` gives for the Python virtual environment when you import `sys` and look at that value.

You also have other things wrong as well though.

Your are missing `WSGIProcessGroup myproject` directive or `process-group=myproject` option to `WSGIScriptAlias`. This means you aren't delegating to the daemon process group where trying to set Python virtual environment.

You also should not set `DocumentRoot` to a directory which includes anything sensitive as a stuff up in Apache configuration could then expose all the files for download.

Finally, when delegating a single WSGI application to a daemon process group, set:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

This avoids problems with some third party Python packages not implemented to work correctly in sub interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this config, and see it works.. The issue is apache is not able to find the python modules path. `WSGIPythonPath` should be taken care.

```
# this section will be commented in the httpd.conf, uncomment them to use virtualhosts
NameVirtualHost *:80


# Add the WSGI settings
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIPythonPath /home/vpalace/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIDaemonProcess vpalace processes=1 maximum-requests=500 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup vpalace


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/palace/
    ServerName www.persiaspalace.us
        Alias /static /home/palace/

    <Directory /home/palace/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
              Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/palace/palace/palace/wsgi.py
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I hit a permissions error  ->  [Mon Apr 03 18:22:01.329985 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 11579] [client 72.178.8.113:38590] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/palace/palace/palace/wsgi.py

Comment: All directories are 0744, files are 0644 and user/group is chown -R www-data:www-data /home/palace

Comment: same original django error now  ->  ImportError: No module named 'django'

Comment: great, then the issue is just its not able to find the path, give the right path where python can find the modules  `WSGIPythonPath`; If you are using virtualenv, (i assume) give `/var/www/html/myportal/src:/var/www/html/myportal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages` for WSGIPythonPath, but make sure you are giving the right path for virtualenv; May be this  `WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/myportal/src:/var/www/html/myportal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: try something like this. https://github.com/rrmerugu/django-seed#running-in-production-mode   it should work  . Also  there is no need for ` python-path=` in `WSGIPythonPath` imo. You didnt put your virtualevn in python path, but you should.

Comment: my v environment path is "/home/vpalace/lib/python3.5/site-packages/" and it is set "WSGIPythonPath python-path=/home/palace/palace/:/home/vpalace/lib/python3.5/site-packages/" . If there is another way to set this piece of crap VE, PLEASE let me know.

Comment: `WSGIPythonPath /home/palace/palace/:/home/vpalace/lib/python3.5‌​/site-packages/` should work. Just restart the apache server, and it should work then !. I dont know if you need 'python-path=' because it is WSGIPythonPath  anyways.

Comment: same, after server reboot   :(

Comment: It is not recommended to use ``maximum-requests`` in a production system. There are other options for recycling process if having memory problems. The reason ``maximum-requests`` is bad is that when you system is under high load it will restart processes more often, which is worst thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on RHEL7, Python3.5, Apache 2.4. Change accordingly. The compiling part of mod_wsgi is the important one. This is using `virtualenv`.

### Apache2.4

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload

chgrp -R apache /var/www/html
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+rx {} +
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod g+r {} +

chown -R myuser /var/www/html/
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod u+rwx {} +
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod u+rw {} +

find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
```

### Python3.5

```
yum install -y https://rhel7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
yum install -y python35u python35u-libs python35u-devel python35u-pip
pip3.5 install virtualenv
```

### mod_wsgi

```
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.5.14.tar.gz
tar -zxvf 4.5.14.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-4.5.14
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.5
make
make install
chmod 755 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

### myportal.conf

vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/myportal.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@email.com
  ServerName myportal
  ServerAlias myportal.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myportal/src/

  WSGIDaemonProcess myportal python-path=/var/www/html/myportal/src:/var/www/html/myportal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
  WSGIApplicationGroup myportal
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myportal/src/myportal/wsgi.py process-group=myportal

  <Directory /var/www/html/myportal/src>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/myportal/src/myportal>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Then execute this command on the shell `systemctl restart httpd`

Comment: I am using Ubuntu (as stated in the post).  I tried that GrahamDumpleton and I might have to delete my entire system just to get it off.  You cannot produce a make uninstall and it fails to install any usable modules (no errors).  :(  That mod is no good at all.

Comment: When you do that type of install from mod_wsgi source code it installed only one file called ``mod_wsgi.so`` into the Apache modules directory. To uninstall just remove the single file after you have removed any manual configuration you yourself added for Apache. You do not have to delete your entire system.